# SQL Server computed column select from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm not to sure what the best way to go about this is, so i'll describe what the end goal is, and if a computed column is the answer then please help me go that route, or perhaps a better route.

I have two tables:

**Orders**

```
OrderId
PackageId
MediaSpend
TotalAdViews (Computed column)
```

**Packages**

```
PackageId
BaseAdViews
```

Each order is assigned a package that comes with say 1,000 views, you can then buy more media spend to get more views. I wanted to create a column called TotalAdViews which would add BaseAdViews + MediaSpend. From my understanding if persistance is enabled the column won't need to recalculate every time it is queried, which could help performance.

How do I get a value from another table in my computed column? Or please suggest an alternate way of accomplishing my goal.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You won't be able to use columns from another table within a computed column expression. This is an extract from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx).

> A computed column is computed from an expression that can use other columns in the same table.

You mentioned that your motivation for using a computed column was to increase performance. There are a lot of [restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) but an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864.aspx) might add value here.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date now and needs updating for the past 12 years' worth of SQL Server releases.

Answer (score 98):

It is perfectly legal to define a user-defined function and use it as the computed value. This function may contain  select statements from other tables.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getAdViews(@packageId int)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @bav int
    select @bav = BaseAdViews from Packages where PackageId = @packageId
    RETURN @bav
END
```

Then in your computed column, just use the expression `dbo.getSumAdViews(PackageId)+MediaSpend` as so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PackageId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MediaSpend] [int] NULL,
    [TotalAdViews] AS dbo.getAdViews(PackageId)+MediaSpend
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: How does this approach compared with join directly in terms of performance?

Comment: True, just note that this wouldn't work in case you want the calculated column to be persisted.

Comment: @liang: According to [sqlcat](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/11/28/a-computed-column-defined-with-a-user-defined-function-might-impact-query-performance/), SQL refuses to parallelize queries which use a computed UDF column. According to [Erik Darling](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/another-reason-why-scalar-functions-in-computed-columns-is-a-bad-idea/), that also means `DBCC CHECKDBB` scripts will refuse to parallelize (which is moot if you're not on Enterprise Edition).

Comment: @LeonardoSpina actually you can make the column persisted (At least in MSSQL) even if you use a user defined function.

Comment: @liang Computed columns with user defined functions is bad for your performance because query optimizer does not extend to user defined functions.

Comment: @erkinyldz You will not be able to make such column persisted because the UDF would be non-deterministic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions and only deterministic columns can be persisted. Any SELECT in the UDF would make it non-deterministic.

Comment: While it is true that a scalar UDF, or a multi statement UDF forces the query plan to drop parallelism, if you can make the function Inline Table-valued, then it is just as efficient as without the UDF. 
I have updated my answer to give such an example.

Comment: @GöranRoseen in SQL Server 2012 at least, this does not seem to work. It is expecting a scalar value, which you can't get by simply invoking the TVF .And to get the scalar through a `SELECT` likewise generates an error, `Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.` Are you certain this will work as you've written it?

The "good" news is the performance seems to be roughly the same as between a view with an inline SELECT and a computed column using a scalar valued function.

Comment: True, @PeterMoore. I changed my answer back to be syntactically correct.
And while I still think that a table-valued UDF can be used, that type of trick to lure the query optimizer is no longer what I would recommend. Before we start optimizing this query, we must know more about the use case. Perhaps a simple view would been sufficient, that would in that case have been more maintainable.

Comment: @GöranRoseen agreed. But even if you don't recommend it I'd love to see a way to do it as a table-valued UDF to trick the optimizer as you mention. I was never able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: What about a scalar UDF with the new `WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON` [option in SQL Server 2019+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver16)? (**UPDATE:** Ah, I failed to read the page I just linked to, where it says: "A scalar T-SQL UDF can be inlined if [...] the UDF isn't used in a computed column or a check constraint definition." - welp, so much for that suggestion).

Answer (score 5):

if it is only for display purposes,why not create a view..

```
select <<add other columns you need>> mediaspend+basicadviews as totaladviews
from 
orders o
join
packages p
on p.packageid=o.orderid
```