# Relating 2 columns in a database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, relational-database

I can't find a way to call the database and ask for it to return specific entries.

I have a database called "Barrios" and another called "Localidades."
"Barrios" has 3 columns: `Id (pk, int)`, `Localidad (Fk, int)`, `Barrio (varchar(50))`

"Localidades" has 2: `Id (PK, int)` and `Zona (varchar(50))`

In "Localidades" I have the states, and in the Barrios I have the neighborhoods.

How do I format my database so that when someone inserts a neighborhood, the associated state is populated as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Barrios inner join Localidades on Barrios.Localidad = Localidades.Id where Localidades.Id = 1
```

thats the sentence, i just made it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function in combination with an expression for the computed column?

[SQL Server computed column select from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867047/sql-server-computed-column-select-from-another-table)