# How to create a computed column that references another column from another table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using Microsoft SQL Server and I am still learning. I have two tables, a product table and an order details table. The product table contains a price and then the order details table has a reference to the the product, the quantity of the product and the total price. Here are the two tables:

```
--Create Product Table
CREATE TABLE Products.Product  
(
    product_id          INT             NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    product_name        VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    product_desc        VARCHAR(5000),
    product_price       SMALLMONEY      NOT NULL    CHECK (product_price >= 0)
);

--Create Order Details Table
CREATE TABLE Orders.Order_detail 
(
    order_detail_id     INT             NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    product_id          INT             NOT NULL,
    product_quantity    INT             NOT NULL    CHECK (product_quantity >= 0),
    order_detail_total  MONEY           NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (product_id)        REFERENCES Products.Product
);
```

How can I make it so that order_detail_total is a computed column that is the `product_price * product_quantity`?

Comment: Hi @kingcobra1986 , I don't have a sqlserver right here but it seems not possible to create a computed column from another table , according to msoft. However, you can create a function that will help you to do so ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867047/sql-server-computed-column-select-from-another-table

Comment: Computed columns **cannot** reference other tables.

Comment: I suppose you could use a TRIGGER for that. Personally I would handle this in a layer above the database layer though.

Comment: I'm with @TT on this, what you're attempting is a business logic layer concern, not a data layer concern

Comment: I'm doing it for two reasons, I'm in a database class, and we are just concentrating on the database and not using any other languages or anything to calculate it and I want the column to be filled. The other reason is just to learn. This isn't for any actual project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Andy K, I came up with this solution:

```
--Create Product Table
CREATE TABLE Products.Product  
(
    product_id          INT             NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    product_name        VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    product_desc        VARCHAR(5000),
    product_price       SMALLMONEY      NOT NULL    CHECK (product_price >= 0)
);
GO

--Create a function to calculate the order details total
CREATE FUNCTION Orders.calcOrderDetailTotal(@quantity INT, @productId INT)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @price SMALLMONEY
    SELECT @price = product_price FROM Products.Product AS TP 
           WHERE TP.product_id = @productId
    RETURN @quantity * @price
END
GO

--Create Order Details Table
CREATE TABLE Orders.Order_detail 
(
    order_detail_id     INT             NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    product_id          INT             NOT NULL,
    product_quantity    INT             NOT NULL    CHECK (product_quantity >= 0),
    order_detail_total  MONEY           NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (product_id)        REFERENCES Products.Product
);
```

This worked for me on a test db that I created.