Optimizing SQL join query with date comparison
I have a query that takes around 2 seconds to fetch 16,900 rows:
SELECT x.lid
FROM schema1.view1 x
INNER JOIN schema1.view2 y
    ON x.cid = y.cid
        and datediff(day, x.indt, y.linvcy)=0    -- problematic line
        and x.indt = y.indt                      -- alternative line I've tried

But if I add time comparison (last line) to the join logic, the query takes over an hour to execute (I've never actually been able to run it to completion).
Each of the views themselves contain join logic so the complexity of the query plan is quite high. I am looking for some pointers to help optimize this query.
schema1.view1:
select
    D.lid,
    D.cid,
    D.indt,
    lower(trim(substring(C.bse, 1, charindex('-', C.bse)-1))) as bse
from (
    select
        B.lid,
        B.cid,
        B.indt
    from ds.v A
    inner join (
        select
            x.lid,
            x.cid,
            x.ivid,
            x.clior,
            x.sosy,
            x.indt
        from rd.ui x
        where
            x.clior like 'abc'
    ) B
    on
        B.ivid like A.ivn
        and B.clior like A.clior
) D
left join ctlg.brchs C
on
    C.paor like D.clior
    and C.sosy like D.sosy
    and C.bid like D.cid

rd.ui:
create table rd.ui (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    lid varchar(256),
    cid varchar(256),
    ivid varchar(256),
    indt date,
    clior varchar(256),
    sosy varchar(256)
)

create unique index idx_unlid
on rd.ui(lid)

create index idx_sebid
on rd.ui(bid)

create index idx_seindt
on rd.ui(indt)

create index idx_sec
on rd.ui(clior)

ctlg.brchs:
create table ctlg.brchs (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    paor varchar(256),
    sosy varchar(256),
    bid varchar(256)
)
create unique index idx_unbr
on ctlg.brchs (paor, sosy, bid)

schema1.view2:
SELECT 
    A.cid
    , A.cinvcy
    , B.linvcy
FROM (
    SELECT
        x.cid
        , MAX(x.indt) AS cinvcy
    FROM schema1.view1 x
    GROUP BY
        x.cid
) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        z.cid
        , MAX(z.indt) AS linvcy
    FROM (
        SELECT
            x.cid
            , x.indt
        FROM schema1.view1 x
        WHERE CONCAT(x.cid, x.ind) NOT IN (
            SELECT CONCAT(y.cid, MAX(y.indt))
            FROM schema1.view1 y
            GROUP BY y.cid 
        )
    ) z
    GROUP BY
        z.cid
) B
ON A.cid=B.cid

I tried creating indexed views using with schemabinding, but those views contain CTEs and derived tables (select * from (select * from x)) which means I can't create indexes on those views.
UPDATE: Changing like to = significantly improved the speed of that part of the query, but the rest is still extremely slow.

Add view definitions, their tables' definitions, and indexes.

it's because every record has to be evaluated individually.  So it must do a full table scan and execute datediff on each record.  You might be better off creating a persisted computed column for the daterdiff which is stored in one of the tables. Perhaps sonmething like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867047/sql-server-computed-column-select-from-another-table.  MSFT DOCS and then index it.

Alternate approach may be to use a materialized view in combination instead of a computed column.  Just depends on real time needs of data.  basically it computes the value of date diff, stores it and then only needs to change on new/updated records.  Thus the join/limit is front loaded for the time sink.

Why would evaluating the datediff for 16900 rows take an hour? Seems like the optimizer got lost.

Hello everyone, I've updated the question with more details. Please let me know if you need anything else.

I have voted to re-open your question. I can see numerous idiosyncrasies in the code you provided. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Why are you using like everywhere? Do you even have wildcards? Or is it a way of handling spaces on join? idiosyncrasies indeed

@Alex I'm using Azure SQL server ... Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 I understand the queries don't look great. What is the most critical thing I should fix first?

@siggemannen Those columns used to be of type text which wouldn't allow comparison by equality. I've since changed those columns to be varchar but haven't actually changed all the likes into =s yet

@siggemannen Please see the update at the bottom of the post.

In schema1.view2 this CONCAT matching is weird.
SELECT
    x.cid
    , x.indt
FROM schema1.view1 x
WHERE CONCAT(x.cid, x.ind) NOT IN (
    SELECT CONCAT(y.cid, MAX(y.indt))
    FROM schema1.view1 y
    GROUP BY y.cid

My understanding is that this query is trying to exclude "last value" (last date?)
Try changing it to:
SELECT x.cid, x.indt
FROM(
    SELECT x.cid, x.indt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY indt DESC ) AS Maxindt
    FROM schema1.view1 x
     ) AS y
WHERE Maxindt <> 1

Try adding the following index to rd.ui table
create index idx_PickYourName on rd.ui(ivid , clior)
As suggested by @siggemannen in the comments please replace all LIKE matches with = where possible.

I tried your solution, but the query had syntax error related to where maxindt <> 1 because the column is not defined. I have also added the specified index but did not notice any significant improvements. However, replacing LIKE with = in every instance improved performance noticeably. I would actually say that replacement has more or less resolved my issues with the queries shared here.

I have posted another (related) question with more details. Please take a look if you have time. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78742499/optimizing-sql-query-joining-views-of-views-is-extremely-slow

RE "where maxindt <> 1" - Sorry about my mistake, see updated query
