Optimizing SQL query - joining views of views is extremely slow
Following question pertains to Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8. The XML I got from Azure Data Studio does not work on Paste The Plan website, so I am sharing the raw XML instead.
I have a dataset of invoices that looks like this (raw_data.invoices):



invoice_id
invoice_date
institution
billed_to
item
qty




12345
2024-07-12
1111
John Smith
phone
20


12345
2024-07-12
1111
John Smith
keys
5


12345
2024-07-12
1111
Jane Smith
keys
2


12346
2024-07-05
1111
John Smith
phone
20


12346
2024-07-05
1111
Jane Smith
keys
2



I have a view that tidies up the above table according to some business requirements (myview.invoices):
select
    D.invoice_date,
    D.invoice_id,
    D.institution,
    C.institution_name,
    lower(trim(substring(C.institution_name, 1, charindex('-', C.institution_name)-1))) as institution_name,
    D.billed_to,
    D.item,
    D.qty
from raw_data.invoices
left join catalogues.institutions C
on
    C.institution_code = D.institution

and a view that identifies the two latest invoice dates for each institution (myview.last_2_inv_cycles):
select 
    A.institution
    , A.current_inv_cycle
    , B.last_inv_cycle
from (
    select
        x.institution
        , max(x.invoice_date) as current_inv_cycle
    from myview.invoices x
    group by
        x.institution
) A
inner join (
    select
        z.institution
        , max(z.invoice_date) as last_inv_cycle
    from (
        select
            x.institution
            , x.invoice_date
        from myview.invoices x
        where concat(x.institution, x.invoice_date) not in (
            select concat(y.institution, max(y.invoice_date))
            from myview.invoices y
            group by y.institution 
        )
    ) z
    group by
        z.institution
) B
on A.institution=B.institution

Eventually, I join those two views together to identify any invoice lines with qty > 15 over the latest two invoices (that come in weekly) (myview.qty_over_15):
with over_2_weeks as (
    select
        x.institution,
        x.billed_to,
        x.item
    from myview.invoices x
    inner join myview.last_2_inv_cycles y
    on x.institution = y.institution
        and (x.invoice_date = y.last_inv_cycle or x.invoice_date = y.current_inv_cycle)
    group by
        x.institution,
        x.billed_to,
        x.item
    having
        sum(case when x.qty > 15 then 1 else 0 end) >= 2

        -- exceptions defined by the business
        and x.institution <> '2222'
)

select
    A.invoice_date,
    A.invoice_id,
    A.institution,
    A.billed_to,
    A.item,
    A.qty
from myview.invoices A
inner join over_2_weeks D

-- problematic join; takes over an hour
on
    A.institution=D.institution
    AND A.billed_to=D.billed_to
    AND A.item=D.item

inner join myview.last_2_inv_cycles C
on
    A.institution=C.institution
    and A.invoice_date=C.current_inv_cycle

-- more exception list
where
    A.billed_to not in (
        'Jake Johnson', 'Bill Gates'
    )

As you can tell, the queries are too complex and take very long (the final view failed to load even after letting it run for over 4 hours). myview.qty_over_15 has the same aesthetic requirements as myview.invoices, which is why I am running the query over the view instead of the raw_data.invoices table; and I would like to keep it this way unless there is a better approach to achieve the same objective.
As for the table definition and indexes on raw_data.invoices:
create table raw_data.uniform_invoices (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key
    , invoice_id varchar(256)
    , invoice_date date
    , institution varchar(256)
    , billed_to varchar(256)
    , item varchar(256)
    , qty int
)

create index idx_search_invoice_id
on raw_data.invoices(invoice_id)

create index idx_search_invoice_date
on raw_data.invoices(invoice_date)

create index idx_search_institution
on raw_data.invoices(institution)

create index idx_invoice_of_institution
on raw_data.invoices(invoice_id, institution)

create index idx_search_billed_to
on raw_data.invoices(institution, billed_to)

create index idx_search_billed_to_item
on raw_data.invoices(billed_to, item)

create index idx_search_bill
on raw_data.invoices(qty, billed_to)

create index idx_search_item_charge
on raw_data.invoices(
    institution
    , invoice_id
    , billed_to
    , item
)

Please help me with these queries. I'm not really sure where to look for more speed.

FYI, Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 is not SQL Server 2012; 2012 was version 11 and also not an Azure build. What you are using is Azure SQL Database. Azure SQL Database uses completely different build numbers to on premises.

SQL Server does not do a good job of optimizing queries with nested views. Avoid them if at all possible.

SQL Performance questions require a) all table definitions b) all index definitions and c) The execution plan using "Paste The Plan". The query itself does not define how it will perform, its a description of the results you want, not how the engine will obtain them.

@DanGuzman That's a very broad statement. You can nest a view 10 times, but if it can simplified then it'll compile back down. And (non-recursive) CTEs, derived tables and subqueries are no different than views in this respect.

I've added the query plan XML as well as the table definition. Please note, you do not need to know about the catalogues.institutions table because it is short and the query runs fast enough for that part. Hence I've included information pertaining to only the raw_data.invoices table

Another technique to get the latest N invoice rows for each group (institution?) is to (1) first identify the institutions of interest and then (2) use the CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP N ...) technique. Something like SELECT * FROM (...choose institutions...) X CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM invoices I WHERE I.institution = X.institution AND ...other criteria... ORDER BY I.invoice_date DESC) I2 Or perhaps just select the top 2 dates with CROSS APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 ...) and then join again to invoices on matching institution and invoice_date.

I believe all queries can be dramatically simplified by using only one window function DENSE_RANK.
WITH invoices AS (
    SELECT
        D.invoice_date,
        D.invoice_id,
        D.institution,
        C.institution_name,
        LOWER(TRIM(SUBSTRING(C.institution_name, 1, CHARINDEX('-', C.institution_name)-1))) as institution_name,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY D.institution ORDER BY D.invoice_date DESC) AS invoice_rank,
        D.billed_to,
        D.item,
        D.qty
    FROM raw_data.invoices
    LEFT JOIN catalogues.institutions C
    ON
        C.institution_code = D.institution
)

SELECT * FROM invoices
WHERE invoice_rank IN (1,2)
AND x.institution <> '2222'
AND billed_to NOT IN (
        'Jake Johnson', 'Bill Gates'
    )
AND qty > 15

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with sum(case when x.qty > 15 then 1 else 0 end) >= 2, if you can clarify why qty > 15 doesn't fit I can adjust the above query to suit the requirement.

sum >= 2 is to check whether the person has met the criteria (qty > 15) over the course of two weeks/cycles, or if this is the first time we are observing this (in which case the record is excluded from the output). I'll try out DENSE_RANK later today and see if it makes a difference.

Okay, I see now. You can try to do it with window functions as well. For example, LAG or COUNT(CASE WHEN qty > 15 END) OVER(PARTITION BY institution).
